# How to select specific class prefix while excluding other prefix?

Tags: css, sass

I need to select the body element when it has a class beginning with `post-type-` but not select it when there's also a class beginning with `taxonomy-`. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

```
body[class^="post-type-"],
body[class*=" post-type-"] {
    &:not([class^="taxonomy-"]),
    &:not([class*=" taxonomy-"]) {
        .widefat {
            .check-column {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: 0stone0's answer below helped me realize the CSS it was outputting was completely wrong, so this new approach is working well:

```
body[class^="post-type-"]:not([class^="taxonomy-"]):not([class*=" taxonomy-"]),
body[class*=" post-type-"]:not([class^="taxonomy-"]):not([class*=" taxonomy-"]) {
    .widefat {
        .check-column {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div[class*='post-type-']:not([class*="taxonomy-"])
```

This pure CSS should target the desired element

---

Select classes that contain `post-type-`, but [`not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) containing `taxonomy-`

```css
div[class*='post-type-']:not([class*="taxonomy-"]) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='post-type-something'>post-type-something</div>
<div class='post-type-something taxonomy-foobar'>post-type-something taxonomy-foobar</div>
<div class='taxonomy-foobar post-type-something'>taxonomy-foobar post-type-something</div>
```

<sub>**Note**: Demo uses `<div>` instead of `<body>` and applies a `border` when targeted</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to get the SCSS working correctly, but your answer helped me realize the CSS it was rendering was all wrong. I have a nice mix of straight CSS and SCSS that is working great. I'm editing my question with my updated SCSS.